# How can i assign a maxValue to a DataTable Column with type decimal? (C#)

Tags: c#

As the title says, I have a DataTable Column of type decimal.
The thing is, only numbers up to 99999 should be allowed to enter.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a database question or do you have some UI control where you want to add validation?

Comment: Do you refer to a UI like DataTable.js or .NET's DataGridView? ADO.NET's DataTable? Or an actual database table? You'll have to add checks on *all* of them starting from the database table and upwards to guard against invalid data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"should be allowed" is a bit vague - what should the result be if someone tried to supply a larger value? Throw an exception? Set it to the max value? Set it to null?

The DataColumn class has a [ColumnChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columnchanging?view=net-5.0) event which is fired when you try to change the value of a field in a `DataRow` so you could register a handler for this event for your decimal column and assess the event args `ProposedValue` property against your max value. Then flag the row as being in error via e.Row.SetColumnError() method.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type of column as `Decimal`, (capital **D**) then when assigning the maximum value of a Decimal to a row, use the `MaxValue` property of the Decimal class.

```
        DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn("column", typeof(Decimal));      
        col.Caption = "Column";
        mytable.Columns.Add(col);
        
        DataRow _rav = mytable.NewRow();
        _rav["column"] = Decimal.MaxValue;
        mytable.Rows.Add(_rav);
        
        foreach(DataRow dataRow in mytable.Rows)
        {
            foreach(var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
         } 
    }
```

When you run the following in the Main method of a console application, the output will be: 79228162514264337593543950335

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E90Yfm)